# copy NSMutableArray item

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nscopying

I am copying a mutable array like this:

```
//copy players' info into playerList from a dictionary
playerList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[params objectForKey:@"p"] copyItems:YES];
```

The items in the array implement copyWithZone like this:

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
   PlayerInfo* copy = [[[self class] allocWithZone:zone] init];
   [copy setNick:[self nick]];
   ...
   [copy setIsChallengedByMe:[self isChallengedByMe]];

   return copy;
}
```

However, playerList only seems to have objects which are "out of scope". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might want to use the simpler playerList = [params objectForKey:@"p"] mutableCopy] by the way.

Comment: What does it mean for an object to be "out of scope"? Variables have scopes, not objects.

Comment: I meant playerList is an array of "out of scope" variables

Comment: @Chuck : I think he mean something about memory management, like you release the object already but some pointers still point to it

Comment: No, I mean I want to use the object I just copied into playerList and I get null. If I debug it and stop it at the next line, it already tells me the object at index 0 is out of scope.. even if the copying has been done as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean they appear "out of scope" in the debugger.  Don't worry about that, it is quite common and doesn't necessarily mean something is wrong.  If you print the description of the array to the console, it should print everything fine.